# Symfony2 Delete Record

Tags: symfony

I am having issues removing a record from my db using Symfony2. Hoping someone can help me out.

Here is my code:

```
// Get user's account
$account = $this->getUser()->getAccount();

// Get manager
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// Get entity
$entity = $em->getRepository('WICPurchaseOrderLineItemBundle:PurchaseOrderLineItem')->findBy(array('account'=>$account->getId(), 'id'=>$id));

// If not entity
if (!$entity) {
throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find this entity.');
}

// Remove the record...
$em->remove($entity);
$em->flush();

// Go to this url...
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('purchaseOrder_view', array('id' => '8')));
```

When this is run, I get this error:

```
 EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given.
```

My URL look like this:

```
 {{ path('purchase_order_remove_line_item', { 'id': purchaseOrderLineItem.id }) }}
```

Does my "id" number need to be turned into an object first? Not sure how to fix this, still learning Symfony.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the `findOneBy` method instead of the `findBy` method.

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('WICPurchaseOrderLineItemBundle:PurchaseOrderLineItem')->findOneBy(array('account'=>$account->getId(), 'id'=>$id));
```